# slideDown on nearest element with a given class, on click

Tags: jquery, slidedown, closest

I have a sort of grid layout, and inside each column is an image, name, title and a written description.

At present written description (`p.sub-team-description`) is hidden using `display:none;`

I want to animate so that when the image is clicked, the description appears by using the slideDown animation.

Because there are many items with the same classnames I have used the jQuery function `.closest()` to try and select only the *closest* instance of this classname.

I cannot see what I have done wrong but it does not work. See JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ddzntq0b/1

```
$( ".sub-team img" ).click(function() {
    $(this).closest("p.sub-team-description").slideDown("fast", function() {});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It's better</strike> I prefer to to hide elements that I'm planning on animating using jQuery itself:

http://jsfiddle.net/uv56z6j6/

```
$(function() {
    $(".sub-team-description").hide();
    $( ".sub-team img" ).click(function() {
        $(this).siblings("p.sub-team-description").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

I also:

- added `slideToggle()`, you may or may not need that, remove it at
  will
- removed the emtpy callback, you should only add it if you're
  actually doing something after the action
- replaced `closest()`    with `siblings()`, since they share the same
  `parent().`

edit: [version with CSS `display:none;` instead of `hide()`](http://jsfiddle.net/996851cf/)

```
$( ".sub-team img" ).click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("p.sub-team-description").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: Could you let us know why it's *better to hide elements that you're planning on animating using jQuery* ?

Comment: CSS rules are a permanent rule you're trying to override. I believe it makes more sense in an stylistic sense. So, it's just personal preference really. I'll rephrase my answer.

Comment: After all, jQuery effects are just animations of CSS properties. I see no advantage at setting the default state through jQuery instead of CSS.

Comment: I've found that sometimes the hiding/displaying animations break if there's a CSS rule involved, but I haven't been able to replicate that right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(this).siblings("p.sub-team-description").slideDown("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the parent element then find the element which you want to slideDown:

```
$(this).parent().find("p.sub-team-description").slideDown();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ddzntq0b/2/)

Comment: You don't **need to** find the parent element, since the `<p>` element is a sibling of the image.

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this...

```
$('.sub-team img').on('click',function(){

    $(this).parent().find('p').slideDown();

});
```